# Text formatting

Tags: php, html

I'm not sure what this would come under so haven't been able to locate a previous answered question.

I am building a small forum system for my website and need some opinions on existing frameworks for formatting text in a safe way?

I'm looking for something basic that will allow users to make things bold or red etc. Just to add html to the text and then validate it.

Could anyone offer any tips on where to find this and how to integrate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Markdown, BBCode and many other simple text formatters are what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, are they easy enough to incorporate?

Comment: Are there any suitable front ends to go with this? Markdown looks like it's just a script to convert.

Comment: They're even included by many forum engines. Well... if you create your own, then you have to implement yourself. Just google up each, their websites usually provide instructions to parse and implement them. Try markdown if you want line by line formatting, and BBCode for more html-like one

Comment: I've gone with BBCode and found a reasonable editor which is a start, I'll build from there. Just wanted to see an example of how it can be done (inc js). Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want an RTE (Rich Text Editor)?

If so you could look at something like TinyMCE here:
http://www.tinymce.com/

It will change a `<textarea>` into an RTE which you can customize in the way you like.
You can then use that  to put data into your database as you would do normally.

Comment: Yeah, this is the type of thing I am after!